# Detecting Ctrl + Return or Ctrl + Enter presses

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent

I find it very hard to find anything official on this matter.

I have a TextView and override the keyDown event and try to detect if the user pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask && /* how to check if enter is pressed??? */)
    {
        NSLog(@"keyDown: ctrl+enter");
        if(_delegate)
        {
            if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSomething:)])
            {
                [_delegate performSelector:@selector(didSomething:) withObject:nil];
            }
        }
    }else
    {
        [super keyDown:theEvent];
    }
}
```

I have tried different things but nothing worked.

anyone?

(i'm sorry to ask such a trivial question but i have googled for a while now and haven't found anything)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
unichar c = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers] characterAtIndex:0];

if(([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask) && (c == NSCarriageReturnCharacter || c == NSEnterCharacter) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the delegate's `textView:doCommandBySelector:`:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    // insertLineBreak: is the method sent when a user presses control-return in a text view
    if (aSelector == @selector(insertLineBreak:)) {
            // do stuff
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding `-keyDown:`, you could override the [keyboard action](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html) (insert a line break) that’s sent when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd> is typed in a text view:

```
- (void)insertLineBreak:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"ctrl-return");

    if(_delegate)
    {
        …
    }
}
```