# How to prevent user from typing the line break in attributed string in NSTextView?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

In `myTextView` I have attributedString and I would like to make the automatic correction of line break i.e. when user cannot make line break. For not attributed string I can use `func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification)` and put there `myTextView.string =  myTextView.string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")`. But, I cannot do this with attributedString as for instance color of part of text will disappear. How can I keep all attributes of the text and to remove possibility for user to make line break ?

Comment: Some ideas: [Detecting Ctrl + Return or Ctrl + Enter presses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361168/detecting-ctrl-return-or-ctrl-enter-presses/7361331#7361331)

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the link !